# How to move and compare column values in sql table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is a code to get free and total disk space of physical drives and the data is stored in a temporary database `#output`.  All I want to do is that I want to compare each value from the `freespace` column available in `#output` table with "1024000" and if the value is less than this then I want to put the value in another table.

I am new to SQL so I don't know how to do this.

P.S. the number of drives can vary so I need a generic solution.

```
declare @svrName varchar(255)
declare @sql varchar(400)

set @svrName = @@SERVERNAME
set @sql = 'powershell.exe -c "Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ' + QUOTENAME(@svrName,'''') + ' -Class Win32_Volume -Filter ''DriveType = 3'' | select name,capacity,freespace | foreach{$_.name+''|''+$_.capacity/1048576+''%''+$_.freespace/1048576+''*''}"'
--creating a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #output
(line varchar(255))
--inserting disk name, total space and free space value in to temporary table

insert #output
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql

select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)'
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
from #output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
order by drivename
```

Comment: sorry for being so vague, I just want to know that how can read the values from a column one by one and compare them with a certain value. suppose I have a column as:

freespace(GB)
40
30
20

now I want to select those rows from this column that are less greater than 20 and put them in another table.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @svrName varchar(255)
declare @sql varchar(400)

set @svrName = @@SERVERNAME
set @sql = 'powershell.exe -c "Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ' + QUOTENAME(@svrName,'''') + ' -Class Win32_Volume -Filter ''DriveType = 3'' | select name,capacity,freespace | foreach{$_.name+''|''+$_.capacity/1048576+''%''+$_.freespace/1048576+''*''}"'
--creating a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #output
(line varchar(255))
--inserting disk name, total space and free space value in to temporary table

insert #output
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql

select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)'
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
from #output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
having (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0) < 20
order by drivename
```

Answering directly to your question in your comment.

When you use functions or calculated fields you can't put them on `WHERE` clause so you have to use `HAVING`. In this solution I used your calculated field for *freespace(GB)*, put it on `HAVING` clause and selected values > than 20.

Tell us if it works, because I don't know if you can use HAVING with those type of functions. If it doesn't work this other solution below:

```
declare @svrName varchar(255)
declare @sql varchar(400)

set @svrName = @@SERVERNAME
set @sql = 'powershell.exe -c "Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ' + QUOTENAME(@svrName,'''') + ' -Class Win32_Volume -Filter ''DriveType = 3'' | select name,capacity,freespace | foreach{$_.name+''|''+$_.capacity/1048576+''%''+$_.freespace/1048576+''*''}"'
--creating a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #output
(line varchar(255))
--inserting disk name, total space and free space value in to temporary table

insert #output
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql

select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)'
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
into #output_2
from #output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
order by drivename

select *
from #output_2
where [freespace(GB)] < 20
```

In this case you are inserting the values from #output in another table (#output_2) so you can use the `WHERE` clause directly.